# Foundation 6 Reveal Modal Tiny Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Below is my sample code for html:

```
<div class="reveal tiny" id="testingOnly" data-reveal>
    <p>testing reveal</p>
    <button class="button" data-close>Close</button>
</div>
<button class="button" onclick="testingOnly.open();">Content Here</button>
```

for javascript:

```
var testingOnly = new Foundation.Reveal($('#testingOnly'));
```

My question is, why does reveal modal always show as large? class `tiny` is not working but `full` does.  I don't know why it's not working.  Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz2mnrdr/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't initialize Foundation on your page for  initializing foundation classes

```
$(document).foundation();
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uz2mnrdr/2/)**

If you download the whole package from their official site, you'll have app.js with just this one line in it.

[documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer